# C# TCP Server buffer

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, protocols

I have been trying to get this to work for a while and I even searched through most of the forum but I've got nothing so far.

My Issue:
Process_send works perfectly in that my client can receive everything that server sends. However, when the client says something, the buffer in the process_receive function is returned as null, even though the TransferredBytes property says "46", which is what it is supposed to be.

Please let me know how I can fix this issue. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace MonkeySyncServer
{
    public partial class ServerForm : Form
    {
        public ServerForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_startServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Server s = new Server(100, 1024);
            s.Init();
            s.Start(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000));
        }


    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the connection logic for the socket server.  
    /// </summary>
    class Server
    {
        private int m_numConnections;   // the maximum number of connections the sample is designed to handle simultaneously 
        private int m_receiveBufferSize;// buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation 
        BufferManager m_bufferManager;  // represents a large reusable set of buffers for all socket operations
        const int opsToPreAlloc = 2;    // read, write (don't alloc buffer space for accepts)
        Socket listenSocket;            // the socket used to listen for incoming connection requests
        // pool of reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs objects for write, read and accept socket operations
        SocketAsyncEventArgsPool m_readWritePool;
        int m_totalBytesRead;           // counter of the total # bytes received by the server
        int m_numConnectedSockets;      // the total number of clients connected to the server 
        Semaphore m_maxNumberAcceptedClients;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create an uninitialized server instance.  To start the server listening for connection requests
        /// call the Init method followed by Start method 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numConnections">the maximum number of connections the sample is designed to handle simultaneously</param>
        /// <param name="receiveBufferSize">buffer size to use for each socket I/O operation</param>
        public Server(int numConnections, int receiveBufferSize)
        {
            m_totalBytesRead = 0;
            m_numConnectedSockets = 0;
            m_numConnections = numConnections;
            m_receiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;
            // allocate buffers such that the maximum number of sockets can have one outstanding read and 
            //write posted to the socket simultaneously  
            m_bufferManager = new BufferManager(receiveBufferSize * numConnections * opsToPreAlloc,
                receiveBufferSize);

            m_readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);
            m_maxNumberAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the server by preallocating reusable buffers and context objects.  These objects do not 
        /// need to be preallocated or reused, by is done this way to illustrate how the API can easily be used
        /// to create reusable objects to increase server performance.
        /// </summary>
        public void Init()
        {
            // Allocates one large byte buffer which all I/O operations use a piece of.  This gaurds 
            // against memory fragmentation
            m_bufferManager.InitBuffer();

            // preallocate pool of SocketAsyncEventArgs objects
            SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_numConnections; i++)
            {
                //Pre-allocate a set of reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs
                readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IO_Completed);
                readWriteEventArg.UserToken = new AsyncUserToken();

                // assign a byte buffer from the buffer pool to the SocketAsyncEventArg object
                m_bufferManager.SetBuffer(readWriteEventArg);

                // add SocketAsyncEventArg to the pool
                m_readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server such that it is listening for incoming connection requests.    
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="localEndPoint">The endpoint which the server will listening for conenction requests on</param>
        public void Start(IPEndPoint localEndPoint)
        {
            // create the socket which listens for incoming connections
            listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
            // start the server with a listen backlog of 100 connections
            listenSocket.Listen(100);

            // post accepts on the listening socket
            StartAccept(null);


        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Begins an operation to accept a connection request from the client 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="acceptEventArg">The context object to use when issuing the accept operation on the 
        /// server's listening socket</param>
        public void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg)
        {
            if (acceptEventArg == null)
            {
                acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(AcceptEventArg_Completed);
            }
            else
            {
                // socket must be cleared since the context object is being reused
                acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
            }

            m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
            bool willRaiseEvent = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is the callback method associated with Socket.AcceptAsync operations and is invoked
        /// when an accept operation is complete
        /// </summary>
        void AcceptEventArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessAccept(e);
        }

        private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connection accepted. There are {0} clients connected to the server",
                m_numConnectedSockets);

            // Get the socket for the accepted client connection and put it into the 
            //ReadEventArg object user token
            SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
            ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = e.AcceptSocket;
            byte[] d = e.Buffer;

            // As soon as the client is connected, post a receive to the connection
            bool willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);

            d = d;
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
            }

            // Accept the next connection request
            StartAccept(e);
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called whenever a receive or send opreation is completed on a socket 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="e">SocketAsyncEventArg associated with the completed receive operation</param>
        void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            // determine which type of operation just completed and call the associated handler
            switch (e.LastOperation)
            {
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                    ProcessReceive(e);
                    break;
                case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                    ProcessSend(e);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
            }

        }

        private bool sendToClient(AsyncUserToken token, SocketAsyncEventArgs e, string s)
        {
            // Send 'Hello World' to the server
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending: " + buffer.Length + " bytes of data");
            e.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);            
            bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(e);
            return willRaiseEvent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is invoked when an asycnhronous receive operation completes. If the 
        /// remote host closed the connection, then the socket is closed.  If data was received then
        /// the data is echoed back to the client.
        /// </summary>
        private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            m_bufferManager.SetBuffer(e);
           // check if the remote host closed the connection
            AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                //increment the count of the total bytes receive by the server
                Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
              //  Console.WriteLine("The server has read a total of {0} bytes", m_totalBytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Received from client: {0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred));


                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
               data = e.Buffer;
             String dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);


                if (dataString.StartsWith("hello"))
                {
                    token.encryptionKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Substring(5, dataString.IndexOf("world") - 5);
                    Console.WriteLine(token.encryptionKey);
                }
               /* bool willRaiseEvent = sendToClient(token, e, "hello world");

                if (!willRaiseEvent)
                {
                    ProcessSend(e);
                }*/



            }
            else
            {
                CloseClientSocket(e);
            }



        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is invoked when an asynchronous send operation completes.  The method issues another receive
        /// on the socket to read any additional data sent from the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void ProcessSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                // done echoing data back to the client
                AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
                // read the next block of data send from the client
                bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
                if (!willRaiseEvent)
                {
                //    e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, listenSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
               //     ProcessReceive(e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CloseClientSocket(e);
            }
        }

        private void CloseClientSocket(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            AsyncUserToken token = e.UserToken as AsyncUserToken;

            // close the socket associated with the client
            try
            {
                token.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            }
            // throws if client process has already closed
            catch (Exception) { }
            token.Socket.Close();

            // decrement the counter keeping track of the total number of clients connected to the server
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
            m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.Release();
            Console.WriteLine("A client has been disconnected from the server. There are {0} clients connected to the server", m_numConnectedSockets);

            // Free the SocketAsyncEventArg so they can be reused by another client
            m_readWritePool.Push(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you've posted over 300 lines of code which is a lot to ask anyone to look through. Can you distill your code down to only the essential bits that cause the issue but still compile?

Comment: FYI to anyone who feels like attacking this problem, it's copypasta with the original source here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.aspx

Comment: thanks, I should have mentioned that this code is from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild-guess based on the code. I suggest you step through this code with a debugger, the answer should be pretty clear when you do.

These lines are suspicious:

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
data = e.Buffer; // reassigns data, so that byte[1024] gets ignored.
String dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); // Ignores the e.Offset value.
```

My guess is that the buffer gets zero-initialized, but for reasons unknown to me the socket data is not read into the start of the buffer, but rather somewhere else. The UTF8 encoder sees a 0 as the first character (0 being the end-of-string signifier in UTF8) and returns an empty string, which is different from null.

Replace the three lines with:

```
String dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);
```